# Как в nginx ограничить доступ по ip?

Tags: nginx, docker

Такие вопросы вопросы уже были, но все равно не получается. Требуется разрешить доступ к одной из страниц только с определенного ip адреса (192.168.0.10). Имеется raspbeery pi с установленной Raspberry Pi OS Lite (64 bit) на ней крутиться докер. Для примера это выглядит так, запускаю докер

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx:alpine
```

захожу контейнер

```
docker exec -it <123456789> sh
```

раскидываю нужные файлы в папку /usr/share/nginx/html

привожу файл /etc/nginx/nginx.conf к такому виду

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        
        location /test/ {
            allow 192.168.0.10;
            deny all;
        }
}
}
```

перезапускаю nginx

```
nginx -s reload
```

но это не работает, доступ в остается с любого адреса в локальной сети.

Логи при заходе с телефона:

```
192.168.0.20 - - [15/Jan/2023:08:32:32 +0000] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; RMX3151) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
2023/01/15 08:32:32 [error] 30#30: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/test/css/bootstrap.min.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.0.20, server: localhost, request: "GET /test/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.30", referrer: "http://192.168.0.30/test/"
192.168.0.20 - - [15/Jan/2023:08:32:32 +0000] "GET /test/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://192.168.0.30/test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; RMX3151) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.0.20 - - [15/Jan/2023:08:32:32 +0000] "GET /test/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://192.168.0.30/test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; RMX3151) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
2023/01/15 08:32:32 [error] 31#31: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/test/css/style.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.0.20, server: localhost, request: "GET /test/css/style.css HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.30", referrer: "http://192.168.0.30/test/"
2023/01/15 08:32:32 [error] 32#32: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/test/js/jquery-3.6.2.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.0.20, server: localhost, request: "GET /test/js/jquery-3.6.2.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.30", referrer: "http://192.168.0.30/test/"
2023/01/15 08:32:32 [error] 30#30: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/test/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.0.20, server: localhost, request: "GET /test/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.30", referrer: "http://192.168.0.30/test/"
192.168.0.20 - - [15/Jan/2023:08:32:32 +0000] "GET /test/js/jquery-3.6.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://192.168.0.30/test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; RMX3151) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.0.20 - - [15/Jan/2023:08:32:32 +0000] "GET /test/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://192.168.0.30/test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; RMX3151) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
2023/01/15 08:32:32 [error] 30#30: *6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/test/js/scripts.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.0.20, server: localhost, request: "GET /test/js/scripts.js HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.30", referrer: "http://192.168.0.30/test/"
2023/01/15 08:32:32 [error] 33#33: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/test/js/handlebars.min-v4.7.7.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.0.20, server: localhost, request: "GET /test/js/handlebars.min-v4.7.7.js HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.30", referrer: "http://192.168.0.30/test/"
192.168.0.20 - - [15/Jan/2023:08:32:32 +0000] "GET /test/js/scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://192.168.0.30/test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; RMX3151) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.0.20 - - [15/Jan/2023:08:32:32 +0000] "GET /test/js/handlebars.min-v4.7.7.js HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://192.168.0.30/test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; RMX3151) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: В конфиге синтаксическая ошибка, `nginx -t` вам покажет где именно

Comment: ; добавил к allow 192.168.0.10, но это не решает проблему

Comment: возможно это связано с тем что все запросы проходят через NAT и nginx видит адреса из сети докера (172.x.x.x), а не вашей локальной 192.168.0.x, хотя в таком случае оно должно было блокировать абсолютно все, хз, можно попробовать запустить с `--network host`, но тогда ваш контейнер будет запускаться не в изолированной сети

Comment: к url `/test/` не должно быть доступа. но, подозреваю, вам нужно отсутствие доступа к `/`, а не к `/test`.

Comment: А в логах доступа какие IP адреса фиксируются? Именно как заходят в /test/ ?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten запуск с этим параметром не изменил ситуацию

Comment: @Alexus логи выглядят так когда захожу с телефона:

Comment: @WhtFck Добавьте директивы access_log и error_log с параметром debug внутри блока location /tests/ чтобы убедиться что nginx заходит в этот location